# Cross-domain, cross-tab communication between co-operating pages

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, local-storage, postmessage

Say I have two tabs, each with a web-page loaded on a different domain.  The pages in the two tabs want to communicate.

The simplest solution I could see was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27234441/472388) *(my answer on a closely-related question I found while searching for duplicates)*, where one  or both of the pages load an intermediate page iFrame, which proxies between `postMessage()` and `localStorage` events.  However, this does require this page to be hosted somewhere, and an extra request by the client.

Are there any techniques for this that wouldn't require a specialised "proxy page" to be served by one of the domains?  (I.e. that could be implemented by a JavaScript library without a supporting server?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between tabs or windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Here the question is about cross-domain.

Comment: why you need two domains ? without a supporting server? ( Impossible )

Comment: Make one server handle an `api` like: `twitter / facebook / youtube / API`,

Comment: And the other server needs to do the  http request  ( get / post )

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd

Comment: @btzr - Definitely not impossible! I actually link to a solution in the question, and it doesn't need any server-side components at all (all sites involved can be 100% static, just using client-side JS).  However, the solution I linked requires an extra HTML page (loaded in iFrame) to act as a proxy, and I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: `However, this does require this page to be hosted somewhere, and an extra request by the client.` ? ^^

Comment: `...without a supporting server?`

Comment: well then I have no idea how to do it except for your answer ^^  :(

Comment: @cloudfeet maybe you can find something useful at https://github.com/wingify/across-tabs - I'm not sure how they implemented it, but it seems like a pretty in-depth implementation of this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript library appears to provide the functionality you're looking for (i.e., supports cross-origin communication between browser tabs). I have not used this yet, but will be trying this out in my application. Check out https://github.com/wingify/across-tabs.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? Does it support cross-origin communication if one of the tabs is not the opener of the other?

Comment: From the docs, this assumes a Parent tab which opens all the others, which isn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably chose to create a backend API service as a common communication tunnel between the 2 different websites.

Eg.

`Site-A send a POST message to https://your-API-service
When Site-B asks for an update to https://your-API-service
Then API service returns the message previously sent from Site-A`

If you need real-time communication you can also use WebSockets or push notifications

Comment: It _can_ be done with just static HTML files (see the link in my question) - compared to that, a backend API just adds complexity and wasted bandwidth, and you're better off with the static-HTML solution.

Answer (score -2):

The window.PostMessage API is what you're looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.

Comment: I know about `postMessage` (and mentioned it in my question), but it can only be used when there's a parent/child relationship between the pages - as in the text you quoted.  I am considering two tabs opened independently.